# `toString` method adding null to object in Dart

Tags: dart

I am working on a Flutter web app, and am using a custom class to keep track of form data. I am instantiating a new instance of the following class:

```
class Contact {
  String name;
  String relationship;
  String phoneNo;

  @override
  String toString() {
    print("""{
      Name: $name,
      Relation: $relationship,
      Phone: $phoneNo
    }""");
  }
}
```

In my controller, once I instantiate, I am printing out the value immediately:

```
// Method in controller, triggered by onTap
Contact contact = Contact();
print(contact);
```

The output is:

```
{
      Name: null,
      Relation: null,
      Phone: null
    }
null
```

Which is causing issues later down the line, as instances of this class are being used as `values` of a `HashMap`. I have narrowed down the issue to being caused by the `toString` method, and when I remove it, `Instance of 'Contact'` is then printed out, as desired. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Your `toString()` method doesn't return a `String`.  It calls `print` directly (and then returns `null` to the caller, which calls `print` on that `null` return value).  If your goal is to remove the stray `null` from the printed output, fix your `toString()` implementation to return the string instead of printing it.

Comment: Of course it does... I don't know how I missed that... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Method in controller, triggered by onTap
Contact contact = Contact();
print(contact);
```

You created a new instance of Contact with no arguments that's why all the value of Contact will be `null`.

*To assign a value there are two solutions:*

**1. Inside from class itself:**

```dart
class Contact {
  String name = 'John doe';
  String relationship = 'Brother';
  String phoneNo = '1234567890';

  @override
  String toString() {
    print("""{
      Name: $name,
      Relation: $relationship,
      Phone: $phoneNo
    }""");
  }
}
```

**2.From outside of Class**

for that, you have to initiate Constructor in your class

```dart
class Contact {
  String name;
  String relationship;
  String phoneNo;

  Contact(this.name, this.relationship, this.phoneNo);
  //You can also choose between named parameters and positional parameters
  // For named parameters Contact({this.name, and so on....})

  @override
  String toString() => """{
      Name: $name,
      Relation: $relationship,
      Phone: $phoneNo
    }""";
}
```

in this scenario you have to pass values where you create instance of class as shown here:

```dart
Contact contact = Contact('John Doe', 'brother', '123456789');
print(contact);
```